# visual studio project on windows is not working properly in visual studio for mac

Tags: c#, angularjs, macos, visual-studio

in windows visual studio community 2015 my asp.net mvc is working but the same project in visual studio for mac is not working. for the word working i mean to say the http request that we make in angular.js to call a specific c# controller return an error of 500 why is that so? Please refer to a document if any Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide error details and code

Comment: 127.0.01:8080/api/packages/umrahs sending the request through this route local host = 127.0.01

Comment: $http.get("api/packages/umrahs").success(
        function (response) {
            $scope.umrahPackagesArray = response;
            $scope.stopCounter();
            $scope.searchData = true;
        });

Comment: this route is working fine in visual studio windows edition but give error 500 bad network request in visual studio for mac